# Truffle Drizzle ContractData call keccak256 error

Tags: contract-development, truffle, react, drizzle

I started with truffle unbox drizzle
then made use of my contract.

I can make use of the ContactForm without error in App.js:

```
<ContractForm
  contract="TheContract"
  method="addData"
  labels={["Title", "Detail"]}
/>
```

However if I call:

```
<ContractData
  contract="TheContract"
  method="getData"
  methodArgs={[accounts[0], 0, { from: accounts[0] }]}
/>
```

It appears as if Drizzle goes through the entire abi and attempts to apply the generateArgsHash and fails at some point where the str is undefined.

Why it does this and not use the method args only, I do not know.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input parameters should be the string (change 0 to "0")

input:`<ContractData
  contract="TheContract"
  method="getData"
  methodArgs={[accounts[0], "0", { from: accounts[0] }]}
/>`

Comment: hmmm, doing that results in:
Error: Returned error: Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10 is not a contract address

0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10 is definitely my contract address.

Comment: try ```methodArgs={[accounts[0], "0"]}```

Comment: It is working now with your original suggestion when I pass the accounts object and not by getting the accounts from the state props I set

const { drizzleStatus, accounts } = this.props;

Only problem now is that, while there are no errors, nothing is displayed