# Truffle with Drizzle fails with TypeError: str.slice

Tags: solidity, truffle, react

Using Drizzle ran into a problem. Can anyone help? There are several get functions

1-st works fine both in the truffle console and at the frontend, function without arguments

**truffle console:**

input: `this.Ethnote.deployed().then(instance => { return instance.getNotebooksCount();}).then(result => {console.log(result);}).catch(e => {console.log(e);});`

output: `BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] }`

**react:**

input: `<ContractData contract="Ethnote" method="getNotebooksCount "/>`

output: `1`

2-nd works only in the truffle console, on the front it falls with an error, function with argument 0 (Notebook index) and returns several outputs

**truffle console:**

input: `this.Ethnote.deployed().then(instance => { return instance.getNotebook(0);}).then(result => {console.log(result);}).catch(e => {console.log(e);});`

output: `[ '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57',
'inbox',
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1521898678 ] },
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 9, c: [ 1521898678 ] },
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] } ]`

**react:**

input: `<ContractData contract="Ethnote" method="getNotebook" methodArgs={[0]} />`

output: `TypeError: str.slice is not a function
    at Object.keccak256 (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:60919:14)
    at Object.sha3 (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:60556:29)
    at DrizzleContract.generateArgsHash (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:69698:39)
    at Function.cacheCall (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:69637:32)
    at new ContractData (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:146699:130)
    at http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27170:19
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:26951:13)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27169:17)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27160:20)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27063:22)
    at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:19468:36)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27246:35)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27133:22)
    at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:19468:36)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27246:35)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:27133:22)
    at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:19468:36)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:26268:45)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:23295:33)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:23114:13)
    at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:19468:36)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:26268:45)
From previous event:
    at new DrizzleContract (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:69583:27)
    at Drizzle.getContracts (http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:69469:58)
    at http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js:69450:17`

Comment: answer is here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43707/truffle-drizzle-contractdata-call-keccak256-error/43787#43787

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with this very thing, when I step though with the debugger it appears that drizzle(?) is going through the whole contract until it hits an undefined str.

At the moment I am not using contractData, still figuring it out, instead I use (modified to your code):

```
getThePrayers(accounts) {
this.contracts.Ethnote.methods. getNotebooksCount().call({from: accounts[0]})
.then(function(_number){
  self.setState({
    notebookCount: _number.toNumber()
 });
});
```

}

in the App constructor I have:

```
this.state = {
  notebookCount: 0
}
```

and use the following in the html

```
{notebookCount}
```

A bit annoying that a simple call to a view function returns a promise.